# In attrs, validate an attributes type is of the enclosing class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I'd like to write a tree `Node` class, with `Node` children, using [attrs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs/), with validation.

The following doesn't compile because `Node` doesn't exist yet -

```
from attr import attrs, attrib
from attr.validators import instance_of

@attrs
class Node:
    left = attrib(validator=instance_of(Node))
    right = attrib(validator=instance_of(Node))
```

Any suggestions how to get my desired behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a solution, but aren't you going to want to be able to set the attributes to None, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dummy `Node` class (call this object A), so that it is a registered name to avoid `NameError` and then you can create your normal class, making sure to inherit from the dummy one (call this object B).

```
from attr import attrs, attrib
from attr.validators import instance_of

class Node:
    pass

@attrs
class Node(Node):
    left = attrib(default=None, validator=instance_of((Node, type(None))))
    right = attrib(default=None, validator=instance_of((Node, type(None))))
```

Technically, the name for object A has been overwritten, but a reference to it is still kept. So when you call `Node()`, you're actually working with an object B. This is both of type object A and object B, but the type that is checked for in `instance_of()` is strictly object A. This is fine for us but explains why the inheritance is important.

```
class Node:
    pass

# This won't work because every `Node` we initialise will be strictly object B,
# but the validator requires a type of object A
@attrs
class Node:
    left = ...
```

Because some nodes will inevitably have to be leaves, you have to also allow for `left` and `right` to be `NoneType`. And finally, providing a default value means you can initialise a node as `Node()`, instead of `Node(None, None)`. For example,

```
>>> tree = Node(right=Node(Node()))
>>> tree
Node(left=None, right=Node(left=Node(left=None, right=None), right=None))
```